# How does this single line for loop work in Python? [list comprehension]

Tags: python

Here is the code sample:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import MySQLdb

def book_list(request):
    db = MySQLdb.connect(user='me', db='mydb', passwd='secret', host='localhost')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM books ORDER BY name')
    names = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
    db.close()
    return render_to_response('book_list.html', {'names': names})
```

The line in particular is:

```
names = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

I just want to understand, how does this line in particular, I understand this is a shorthand way of doing things, but could someone provide how the long version would look like?

Comment: it's called list comprehension, and is explained in the python doc very well

Comment: http://carlgroner.me/Python/2011/11/09/An-Introduction-to-List-Comprehensions-in-Python.html

Comment: Thanks, I changed the title if anyone in the future were to ask the same question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That line is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  Here is a 'long' version.

```
names  = []

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    names.append(row[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was looking for what this kind of syntax was called exactly. Thanks a lot for the answer.